# Balance the units of the following hamiltonian

Tags: hamiltonian, units, dimensional-analysis, spin-chains

The following image is taken from an article and shows the hamiltonian of a spin chain model. I knew that the dimensional units in an equation must balance. To ensure this, the author took a procedure (as shown in the shaded part). With this procedure, he concluded that all parameters, J1, J2, and `\lambda`, have no units and hence the equation is balanced.
I cannot understand this step and what is the final unit of the equation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All three coefficinets have dimensions of energy, so  $J_2/J_1$ and $\lambda/J_1$ are dimensionless.

Comment: But what he means by abs[J1]=1? and he said that all parameters are dimensionless, not the rations J2/J1 and λ/J1.  @mike_atone

Comment: He just takes $J_1=1$ in whatever units he feels like. None of it affects anything. The phases of the spn chain are determined only by the ratios of the couplings. Nobody cares about the overall-energy scale in these type of models.

Comment: By  "scaled to $J_1$" he means divided by $J_1$.